# Angular ng-model not binding to input fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, viewmodel, angular-ngmodel, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have the following controller working and I can use ng-repeat to display the ONE json object I have. I just used ng-repeat to make sure the data was actually coming across. But I can't figure out how to bind my input fields to show the data inside the text fields in this edit view/template.

**Controller**

```
angular
    .module("renderIndex", ["ngRoute","ngCookies"])
    .config(config)
    .controller("favoritesController", favoritesController)
    .controller("newFavoriteController", newFavoriteController)
    .controller("editFavoriteController", editFavoriteController);

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        //...left out for brevity

        .when("/editfavorite/:searchId", {
            templateUrl: "/ng-js/ng-templates/editFavoriteView.html",
            controller: "editFavoriteController",
            controllerAs: "vm"
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
};

//...left out for brevity

function editFavoriteController($http, $window, $routeParams) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.search = [];

    var url = "/api/favorites/" + $routeParams.searchId;
    $http.get(url)
        .success(function (result) {
            vm.search = result;
        })
        .error(function () {
            alert('error/failed');
        })
        .then(function () {
            //Nothing
        });
};
```

The controller works, it accepts a parameter of id and that is is used and tacked onto the end of the api endpoint URL. I get back a good response that is one json object, I am able to pass that over to the view using `vm.search` and if you notice at the bottom of the view I have a `ng-repeat` (which is only there because I wanted to make sure that some data was actually coming over the wire and it is. Of course it only repeats one record because this is an edit page, but it works, but my binded inputs are not showing anything in the text fields when the view renders. This has to be something simple, can anyone help?

**EditView/Angular Template**

```
<div class="small-12 column"><h3>Edit Search</h3></div>
<div class="small-12 column">
    <form name="editFavoriteForm" novalidate ng-submit="vm.update()">
        <input name="userId" type="hidden" ng-model="search.userId" />
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" ng-model="vm.search.name" />
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="30" 
                  ng-model="vm.search.description"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="tiny button radius" value="Save" /> | 
        <a href="#/" class="tiny button radius">Cancel</a>
    </form>
</div>
<div data-ng-repeat="s in vm.search">
    <p>{{s.name}} - {{s.userId}}</p>
</div>
```

So just to reiterate.... Data is being sent over in `vm.search` and it is the one database record that I am expecting, I know it is because it displays when I use `ng-repeat`. But when I use `ng-model='vm.search.name'` I don't get the data bound to the field so that I can edit it. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

As you can see below I put some test data in and went to the edit page for that item, name=asdf & userId=fec87a96-22d7-4e8c-8991-fa01df60c5c0. Which are both expected values, but nothing shows up in the bounded text fields using the same vm.search model.

[image]

Comment: Looks like `vm.search` is an array so you can't bind to properties like `vm.search.name`. The simplest correct example would be `ng-model="vm.search[0].name"`

Comment: Is there something on the controller side I could like cast it to an object instead of an empty array? Kind of like this: `vm.search = {};`

Comment: I'm open to any suggestions, my controller is built the only way I know how but if I'm doing something wrong I will change it, What is standard syntax in controller for something like this?

Comment: the suggestion you made in your comment about using `vm.search = {}` instead of `vm.search = []` seems logical.  Did you try it?

Comment: Let me do that real quick and see what happens...... Yeah nothing happens, I get the same results. The guys answer below suggests to use $scope, but everything I have done using `controller as` was to keep from using `$scope` I might try his example, but I am trying to create this application consistent with the other controllers I have and so far I have been using `controller as` everywhere with much success.  It's just this one view where I am trying to setup an edit page where I have had trouble.

Comment: You seem to be mixing arrays and objects without thinking about what it should be. If you only expect one object in the AJAX response, then use `vm.search = result[0]` in your controller. Using this though, you will not be able to use the `ng-repeat` as is. For simply dumping the data, I would just use `<pre>{{ vm.search | json }}</pre>` instead of the repeat

Comment: Alternatively, you could wrap the forms in a similar `ng-repeat` and bind the models to `s.name`, `s.description`, etc

Comment: Yep I have used `<pre>{{ vm.search | json }}</pre>` before, not sure why I was using ng-repeat, maybe because I'm a noob and just was the first thing I went for to make sure data was there. Good point. I guess what you are saying is to set `vm.search` inside the http function and not worry about initializing it? Or do I still need to initialize it using `vm.search = {}` and obviously not use `vm.search = []` or does that even matter? BTW I'm trying your solution now.

Comment: You don't need to initialise it.

Comment: @phil WORKED PERFECT! so by assigning `vm.search` to `result` that was assigning it the entire array (OF ONE). which was causing the problem. And by knowing we are only getting one result back and that we will not be iterating over it, result[0] gives us just that first result and allows the binding to work?

Comment: @Phil, IF you want  credit for the answer, maybe you could go ahead and paste the solution into an answer, otherwise I will have to answer the question myself tomorrow, would rather give you credit though... I do thank you very much for the time you took to answer my question. Thanks again, any additional knowledge you can impart on me about this problem would be appreciated if you have the time otherwise, I will make sure I give a good answer based on your response for anyone who might run across this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty simple here, thanks to Phil. First off I should not have been using `ng-repeat` at the bottom of my code as a way of testing to see if my values were there, it is much better to use something like:

```
 <pre>{{ vm.search | json }}</pre>
```

This spits out (in a code view) the actual json object that is being held in `vm.search` and the `| json` appended after the variable name just helps to format the json out on the page. If you did not use it you would just see everything on one line. So again @Phil, thank you for the tip!

One thing I wasn't realizing is that my `result` from the `http.get` call which I was stuffing into the `vm.search` variable. Is actually an array. OBVIOUSLY you say, but it didn't dawn on me to only grab the first item from that array and stuff that in my variable named `vm.search` instead I was doing this:

```
$http.get("/api/favorites")
.success(function (result) {
    vm.searches = result;
})
```

When in fact I should have been doing this:

```
$http.get("/api/favorites")
.success(function (result) {
    vm.searches = result[0];
})
```

Now to look at the difference let's save out the result that we get from

```
 <pre>{{ vm.search | json }}</pre>
```

using each method, first without targeting the first array element, we get:

```
[
  {
    "searchId": 91,
    "userId": "fec87a96-22d7-4e8c-8991-fa01df60c5c0",
    "name": "xxx123",
    "description": "123xxx",
    "created": "2015-03-11T01:12:37.32",
    "searchString": "/?"
  }
]
```

Now if we extract the result using the latter method, going straight for the first element `result[0]` we get the results as an object, not an object contained within an array of only one item.

```
{
  "searchId": 91,
  "userId": "fec87a96-22d7-4e8c-8991-fa01df60c5c0",
  "name": "xxx123",
  "description": "123xxx",
  "created": "2015-03-11T01:12:37.32",
  "searchString": "/?"
}
```

I know this seems tedious to explain all of this, but for someone like me who overlooked it, this is the difference between your model binding or not binding to the input values for each text field and even though it's very simple it's very possible that other noobs like myself would overlook this. I'm sure someone could better explain exactly what the difference is between the two.

Feel free ANYONE to edit my answer and better explain, especially if it takes less lines of code to do so!

Answer (score -4):

The way controller and view talk to each other is through $scope. In your case the controller's vm variable is local to controller and is not available to view as you are declaring it as `var vm`.

When you access vm in view, it actually creates a new variable vm and put it on scope.

To correct it you need to pass $scope as controller dependency and use $scope.vm in your controller. Your controller should look like:

```
function editFavoriteController($scope, $http, $window, $routeParams) {
    $scope.vm.search = [];

    var url = "/api/favorites/" + $routeParams.searchId;
    $http.get(url)
        .success(function (result) {
            $scope.vm.search = result;
        })
        .error(function () {
            alert('error/failed');
        })
        .then(function () {
            //Nothing
        });
};
```

With these your view and controller should now refer to same 'vm' variable available in $scope.

Please note that you need not to explicitly use $scope.vm in your view as 'vm' is implicitly refers to $scope.vm in view.

Comment: I just added the rest of my controller, you will see that I am using the `controller as` syntax and tacking my variables onto `.this` which I am aliasing as `vm` I was under the impression that this was possible and I could bind my model to my view using this method instead of `$scope` Most of what I have learned about using `controller as` was learned here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: Sanket, I do understand what you are saying, I actually learned Angular using `$scope`, but I am trying not to use $scope in that manner anymore.  I want to let you know that I did not downvote your answer, but it is not the answer I'm looking for because of the fact that I am trying to code with the Angular-Style Guide in mind. I do however thank you for reaching out and taking the time to explain your answer. @Phil was able to answer the question in a comment above.

Comment: No worries Eric. Glad you found the answer.